# Automatically create a list based on dynamic xml

Tags: sharepoint-designer, email, xml

I am trying to set up a SharePoint page as follows (using SPdesigner), but don't know if it is possible and where to start.

We want a page where a list is displayed, and the content of the list should be based on data from a database.
But now the question: This database should be filled (updated etc) from XML emails that arrive at a defined SharePoint-inbox.

1. an email with XML content is sent to a SharePoint email address
2. SharePoint sees the email, reads the content
3. XML content is being checked and the data is inserted to the page/list database.

is this possible and any tutorials/help on this topics (read email, XML to db/list) plz?

*(i'm fairly new to SharePoint so my apologies if question sounds strange :) i know how to easily do it on f.e. php but that's not 'allowed' here where we want to implement it...)*

Comment: U have to add data in list which are come from email with XML format?

Comment: @V_B yes, somebody sends an email with XML format, and I want to add this to a existing list. But don't know how

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there a solution?

Comment: @Jens looking at the amount of replies I don't think so